# Is there a method to get the jSoup jar version?

Tags: jsoup

I am not a java programmer and I am using jSoup in a ColdFusion application, and my java knowledge is limited.

I looked in the docs but could not find a method to tell me which version of jSoup is loaded. Maybe there is a standard java method for that?

It is necessary because I am using it on a shared hosting and I want to ensure I have the correct compatible version loaded.

Thanks,
Murray

Answer (score 0):

Usually you either supply the java runtime environment with a version of the library you want to use somewhere on the classpath, or you use a build tool to manage dependencies for you.

Typically the latter is preferred.

e.g. I use gradle for just about every project. To add gradle to your project, download/install gradle, open a terminal, cd to the project's root dir, execute `gradle init` and then you end up with a few additional files in your project.

One of the files in the project's root dir is `build.gradle` this contains many things - one is the project `dependencies`. Here's an example of one I use for JSoup projects:

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

test { useJUnitPlatform() }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
}
```

Here you can see the exact version of the library dependency and you can check it with `gradle dependencies` if you wanted to check for a version clash due to another library importing a different/newer version you weren't expecting.

Another method is simply to download the library and place is somewhere on the classpath so your application can access it.

Comment: Thanks Rob. In my situation using ColdFusion we instantiate the java class from the CF environment then use its methods. eg `jSoup = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" );` then eg `dom = jSoup.parse(html);`. I was hoping for a `version = jSoup.version();` type of thing so I can check from within ColdFusion at runtime.

Comment: perhaps manually add a getter method and hard code something in environment variables until you figure out a better solution ? Alternatively I was thinking perhaps there's something in the MANIFEST inside the jar... so maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889510/can-i-determine-the-version-of-a-java-library-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will explore those options. Much appreciated.