# parsing a londonstockexchange page using jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, web, web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently trying to get the data from the following link

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/RIO/rio-tinto-plc/fundamentals

to be able to receive everything under income-statement, balance sheet etc. However I have been unsuccessful getting a table name to get the elements below each category. Does any one know how to do this using Jsoup ?

```java
try {
    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/RIO/rio-tinto-plc/fundamentals").get();
    Elements masthead = (document.select("th.table-header th"));
    for (Element row : document.select("table.table-header")) {          
        System.out.println(row.select("table:nth-of-type(2)").text());
    }
} //end of try 
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data for that page is embedded.. or to put it another way, its a single page app and you're looking in the wrong place for the data.

Another thing: following my extensive research into this particular web-scrape session, embedded in the data is a note saying

> This data is provided by FTSE Russell Data Solutions...

You might prefer to obtain this data more directly.

https://www.ftserussell.com/data/equity-data

Before I got to that stage though I managed to come up with a JsonSoup version that gets pretty close, but requires significant effort to get exactly the data you want. Since I don't really know whether you just want the headlines this is as far as I got before deciding its close enough for you to take over and adapt it.

One other point to note: I'm using Jayway's JsonPath to extract data from the JSON:

```java
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.util.List;

public class LondonStockExchange {

    public static final String URL = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/RIO/rio-tinto-plc/fundamentals";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .get();
            Elements jsonTag = document.select("#ng-lseg-state");

            String data = jsonTag.get(0).data().replace("&q;", "\"");
            System.out.println(data);

            // 2nd array here likely contains what you want:
            List<String> relevantData = JsonPath.read(data, "$..body.components[*].status.childComponents[*].content");

// These return deeply-nested data structures:
//            List<String> fundamentals = JsonPath.read(data, "$..body.components[*].status.childComponents[*].content.fundamentals");
//            List<String> titleBalanceSheet = JsonPath.read(data, "$..body.components[*].status.childComponents[*].content.titleBalanceSheet");
//            List<String> titleRatios = JsonPath.read(data, "$..body.components[*].status.childComponents[*].content.titleRatios");

            // do stuff with the data
            System.out.println(relevantData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using a good IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) you can take the JSON, copy it from the console output, paste it to a .json (scratch) file and format it immediately with `Code` -> `Reformat Code` which will lay it out nicely for you with minimal effort. Then just follow the keys for the bits of data you want to extract... hint: `Find` the data values you want in the JSON and work backwards from there to construct the relevant JsonPath (much like DOM navigation).

Good Luck

Comment: Hi Rob,Thank you very much for your help. It is greatly appreciated. I managed to extract  quite a lot of data using your suggestions. I can see all the relevant info coming out which is great! However, I am not able to find the Jway library. I am using Netbeans as IDE. Any suggestions? Many thanks Demis

Comment: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/releases (download jar from github releases) OR see here about using a build tool (gradle) which simplifies adding library dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/a/64866730/7619034

Comment: Thank you so much Rob. You are great.